# Django Login with preset single Username and Password

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to create a simple login page, for anyone who has the username and password should be able access to some specific links.

I found some tutorials which teach registration, login, logout using auth templates, but they need me to do user registration first. 
I could not find any basic tutorial, which can just help me set a default username and password, without creating a signup page.

I know this question is not specific, but any heads up will be very helpful!

Comment: you mean you will create users manually in django admin panel? And not give a signup page for users?

Comment: yes.. I want to do that. I want to create only one username and password

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create a signup page, simply don't create it.

Only create a login page.

Another thing, you want to give access to specific links only to those who have a username password,

I do it by this way,

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Sign Out</a></li>
 {% else %}
     <li><a href="{% url 'signup' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
 {% endif %}
```

Its simple enough. Don't create the signup view and template. Just create the login,logout view and template.